# data input not under column headers, i am trying to display the data in straight line columns...but its not working

Tags: android, sqlite

hello am new at android development. am creating an app that has four columns. Student, age, number and class...but the data displayed under the columns is disorganized, how can i organize the data displayed in proper columns?

here is my code. 
my database name = schooldatabase

```
String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_STUDENT, KEY_AGE, KEY_ID_NUMBER, KEY_CLASS };
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

String result =  "";
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();                

int IROW = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
int ISTUDENT = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STUDENT);
int IAGE = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
int INUMBER = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_NUMBER);
int ICLASS = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CLASS);
// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    result = result + c.getString(IROW) + " " + c.getString(ISTUDENT)
        + " " + " " + c.getString(IAGE) + " " + " "
        + c.getString(INUMBER) + " " + "  " + c.getString(ICLASS)
        + "\n";
}

return result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rawQuery` to query items as what you want column like:

```
ourDatabase.rawQuery("select <your columns order>" +  from + DATABASE_TABLE,null);
```

And I think whether the data is ordered depends on how you resolve this data,when you get all data you can handle these as you want order.

Comment: @firesun...where should i use that query?

Comment: replace `Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
`

Comment: like this?
String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_STUDENT, KEY_AGE, KEY_ID_NUMBER, KEY_CLASS };
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(" select <columns> " + from + DATABASE_TABLE, null);